# Wmi win32 classes on x64

Tags: wmi, 64-bit

I'm developing .net application using wmi and win32_* WQL queries.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394084(VS.85).aspx
Will such application work on x64?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Those class names work the same on 64-bit Windows. The "Win32" part just wasn't changed for compatibility reasons. After all, everything you can query is the same regardless of bit-ness, anyway.

You can easily play around with those in PowerShell and the `Get-WmiObject` cmdlet. This works without problems for both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of PowerShell (which itself is a .NET program too).

Comment: Bonus point for your edit that adds why Win32 is still called Win32.